# What are the different ays to capture images sent to a Messenger chatbot

Tags: node.js, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm capturing images sent to my chabot to do some OCR processing, but Messenger compresses the images depending on the user's device / settings / app version / internet spot. It seems there are several ways to get the image sent, some having better resolutions than others.

I'm currently getting the image from the payload attachments, but I need a comprehensive answer as to what are the other options and what request I should send exactly. 
There is no such guide in Facebook documentation or anywhere I've looked on the world wild web.

Comment: _“It seems there are several ways to get the image sent, some having better resolutions than others.”_ - is that based on that you have tried several ways, or that these are documented somewhere - or how exactly does it “seem” that way?

Comment: I understand this from comments I've read on the Messenger developers group on Facebook ([example](https://www.facebook.com/groups/messengerplatform/permalink/740882332955412/)). I find it strange there's no comprehensive thread on this matter anywhere as I guess I'm not the only one doing computer vision on images received via Messenger. I also understand there is an [image_data field accessible from facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages/) but that's not related to the send  api

Comment: @04FS Do you have any lead?

Comment: No, and I’m not a member of the group mentioned, so I can’t see what those posts say either. Would suggest you ask the people there directly if they can clarify/provide more details.